# Networking problems with submitting Spark application

Tags: apache-spark

I want to submit Spark application from my laptop to a Spark cluster in standalone mode. They are in the same network and have routable IP addresses.

I can get it to work if I disable firewall on my laptop. But, if I have firewall enabled, it fails while trying to connect to the master node. The following error message seems to indicate that the driver can't get any resources.

```
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Next, I try setting the `spark.driver.port` in my driver program. I then open up that particular port on the driver machine. This gets past the first error, but gives me a new error.

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 172.31.51.158): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:555)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:356)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$3.apply(Executor.scala:393)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$3.apply(Executor.scala:390)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:390)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems like the master and driver are able to use the `spark.driver.port` to get something started, but failed later? It still seems like it's some kind of networking problem.

Comment: Do you use your laptop as *the* driver? If this is the case there are many other ports required to be open. Web UI `8088` and `4040`, REST API `6066`, several -if not many- akka TCP connections, and `spark.fileserver.port`. IMHO, best solution is to ssh into master node and submit your jar/py within.

Comment: @mehmetminanc  yes I am using laptop as driver. you're right - having laptop as driver means needing to open a whole bunch of ports on my machine. i had to also open `spark.blockManager.port`.  so i guess i'd need to rsync my source code over to a temp directory on master node and then run spark inside an SSH if i want interactive spark?

Comment: Good idea, even better is to ssh into master and use `spark-shell` for interactive use.